Configure SSL on guacd docker image
I am running a guacd container on a host that will be accessed from a guacamole server on another host.
I want to encrypt the traffic between.
https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/guacamole-docker.html#running-guacd-for-use-by-the-guacamole-docker-image
These docs do not state how to provide an SSL certificate to guacd to set up SSL. The Dockerfile is also not giving me any pointsers.
Is it possible to do this with the Docker image, or will I have to go in other directions (manual setup or my own docker image)?
